# Responsive mobile bootstrap 5 superposición de divs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-5

estoy aprendiendo lo basico sobre html y css, iniciando en bootstrap y haciendo uso de scss, pasando mi primer proyecto a responsive, me encuentro con la dificultad de que ciertos divs se me sobreponen en los breakpoints de mobile, siendo que no defino la cantidad de columnas que ocupa cada uno (entiendo que si no los defino ocupan toda la fila), solo están definidas para breakpoints md.

Captura de como se ve en visión tablet:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Captura de superposición en mobile:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comparto código de algunos de los divs que se superponen, espero que me puedan dar una mano ya que estoy dando vueltas hace varios días sobre el problema, intentando separar en secciones, definiendo columnas de brakpoints mobile y demás soluciones que fueron apareciendo pero ninguna fue efectiva.

Saludos!

```
       <section class="row sectionSegunda">
            <div class="sectionSegunda__div-parrafo col-md-12">
                <div class="row rows">
                    <div class="divFlex col-md-7 col-sm-12">
                        <p class="sectionSegunda__parrafo">
                            Los Esteros del Íbera cuyo nombre proviene del guaraní (Aguas Brillantes),
                            conforman un extenso humedal que abarca aproximadamente 12.000 kilometros cuadrados,
                            reconocidos por ser uno de los ecosistemas subtropical y tropical con mayor diversidad
                            a nivel global y cuya configuración resulta en el inmaculado paisaje observado en las fotos de difusión.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 sectionSegunda__div-carousel">
                        <h2 class="tituloSecundario">Te presentamos nuestra galeria de imagenes para que conozcas más sobre este increíble ecosistema</h2>
                        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">
                            <div class="carousel-indicators">
                                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img src="images/carousel1.jpg" class="carousel__imagenes d-block w-100" alt="caracol">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="images/carousel2.jpg" class="carousel__imagenes d-block w-100" alt="lechuza">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="images/carousel3.jpg" class=" carousel__imagenes d-block w-100" alt="ave">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                            </button>
                            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```